# Converting Protobuf3 with enum to JSON in Go

Tags: json, go, enums, protocol-buffers, grpc

How can I convert `grpc`/`protobuf3` message to `JSON` where the `enum` is represented as `string`?

For example, the `protobuf` message:

```
enum Level {
    WARNING = 0;
    FATAL = 1;
    SEVERE = 2;
    ...
}

message Http {
    string message = 1;
    Level level = 2;
}
```

Is converted by:

```
j, _ := json.MarshalIndent(protoMessage, "", "\t")
```

To:

```
{
    "message": "Hello world!",
    "level": 2,
}
```

I wish to get:

```
{
    "message": "Hello world!",
    "level": "SEVERE",
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I found out that I should use the `protobuf/jsonpb` package and not the standard `json` package.

so:

```
j, _ := json.MarshalIndent(protoMessage, "", "\t")
```

Should be:

```
m := jsonpb.Marshaler{}
result, _ := m.MarshalToString(protoMessage)
```

#### Update

As noted bellow, `jsonpb` is depricated and the new solution is to use [protojson](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson)

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, be aware that `jsonpb` has been deprecated in the meantime. As recommend by others, `protojson` is the new way to go.

Answer (score 8):

I found some of these modules (jsonpb) to be deprecated. What worked for me was the google encoding version:

```
import "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"

jsonString := protojson.Format(protoMessage)
```

Answer (score 3):

Level is not a string though, it is an emum.  There are really only two choices I see.

1. Write a custom marshaller that does this for you
2. Generate code that does this for you.

For #2, gogoprotobuf has an extension (still marked as experimental) that let's you do exactly this:

https://godoc.org/github.com/gogo/protobuf/plugin/enumstringer and
https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/blob/master/extensions.md

Comment: `gogo` was not required for my specific problem. Thanks for the refer, it might help with other issues

Comment: The current golang protobuf lib (v1.3) is already replacing the enum values by string. 
However, to make the default value visible, you must set the Marshaler 'EmitDefaults' option to true:
 jsonpb.Marshaler{
  EmitDefaults: true,
 }

Answer (score 3):

For my use case, I wanted to write it to a file. Using the most recent packages as of this date, this was as close to a regular `encoding/json` marshal as I could get.

I used the `google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson` package and the `.ProtoReflect().Interface()` methods of my protocol buffer data structure.

```golang
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"

    "myproject/proto"
)

func main() {
    myProtoStruct := proto.MyType{}

    data, err := protojson.Marshal(myProtoStruct.ProtoReflect().Interface())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to JSON marhsal protobuf.\nError: %s", err.Error())
    }

    err = ioutil.WriteFile("my.proto.dat", data, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to write protobuf data to file.\nError: %s", err.Error())
    }

    log.Println("Written to file.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to serialize the json object, this would be helpful.

```
var msg bytes.Buffer
m := jsonpb.Marshaler{}
err := m.Marshal(&msg, event)
```

`msg.Bytes()` converts `msg` to byte stream.

Answer (score 1):

this is a very old question, but I will post my solution, maybe someone on the future will also face the same issue.

firstly, `jsonpb` is deprecated.
secondly, when you use `protojson`, you can set your options, which will affect the outcome JSON. In your case, the option `UseEnumNumbers` says how you want to marshall enums, strings or ints. Like so:

```
arr, err := protojson.MarshalOptions{
        UseEnumNumbers: true, // uses enums as int, not as strings
    }.Marshal(a)
```